# Why $\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^5)$ is false?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, education

I'm wondering why the following use of little o is incorrect.

$$
\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^5)
$$

I know that te definition of little o is the following:

$$
f(x) = o(g(x)) \quad \text{when } x \to x_0 \qquad \text{if } f(x)=g(x) \, w(x) \quad \text{with } \lim_{x \to x_0} w(x) = 0
$$

In my case should be $x_0=0$, $f(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6}$, and  $g(x) = x^3$. It seems that the limit tends to infinity, but the same situation happens if I consider (the following is correct):

$$
\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^4)
$$

---

Answer suggested by the guys below: in the first case we have:

$$
w(x) = \frac{\sin(x) - \left( x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \right)}{x^5} =
\frac{x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \left( x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \right)}{x^5} = \frac{1}{5!}
$$

so:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} w(x) = \frac{1}{5!} \neq 0
$$

Instead in the second case:

$$
w(x) = \frac{\sin(x) - \left( x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \right)}{x^4} = \frac{x - \frac{x^3}{3!} - \left( x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \right)}{x^4} = 0
$$

so:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} w(x) = 0
$$

Comment: Consider $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x -(x-\frac{x^3}6)}{x^5}$.

Comment: @user thank you very much for your useful comment.

Comment: $\frac{\sin(x) - \left( x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \right)}{x^4} = \frac{x - \frac{x^3}{3!} - \left( x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \right)}{x^4}$ is not true since $\sin x \neq  x - \frac{x^3}{3!}$.

Comment: Hello @Gary can you write your answer please? It'd be easier to understand the right result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the sentence $\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^5)$ is NOT saying that $f(x) = o(x^5)$ where $f(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6}$. It is saying that $f(x) = o(x^5)$ where $f(x) = \sin(x) - x + \frac{x^3}{6}$. Now use the Taylor expansion for sine.